# Allowing components to control themselves in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In NextJS, I am trying to find a way where a component will gather and display its data alone, without the help of the Page. For example I have a header that is on all Pages. That header contains some profile information and other data. I cannot use `getInitialProps` in the component as it can only be declared once on the page right?
So what solutions do I have?

1. Pass the data always from `getInitialProps` on the page to the sub
   components, but would mean I always have to gather that data in my
   api call in getInitialProps which gets annoying
2. HOC could be used but then the component will sort of have an empty
   state until the data is gathered which doesnt look good.

So basically I am trying to figure out how to best have reusable components that are on every page such as a header.

How do i get the data for these components without having to always pass it in from `getInitialProps`?

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear. Please try to explain more about what you are trying to solve / understand. An example with some code could help.

Comment: So basically I am trying to figure out how to best have reusable components that are on every page such as a header. How do i get the data for these components without having to always pass it in from getInitialProps?

Comment: Can you provide a piece of code to show how you use getInitialProps.